# which ubuntu kernel codecs should be removed to disaple images support

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

I am trying to build a Ubuntu kernel that prevents users from opening images and videos.
for that, I downloaded the Ubuntu kernel and using make menuconfig, I removed the multimedia support drivers from the kernel. but after installing the new kernel the OS is still opens images.

So I am missing the right drivers, my question is which drivers should I remove from the kernel to prevent the OS from opening images?